# Generate a username using string parameters

Tags: java, string

I'm new to Java. I am tasked with creating a menu program, one option is to generate a username in the form of first initial and surname.
The method is `stringOperation(String f, String s)`
Variables are `fName` and `sName`.

Here is the code. I have highlighted the areas I need help with. The rest of the code is OK, I think. This is a section of the pseudocode that explains what is required:

`stringOperation(String f, String s)`

- 3.1.1    Assign first character of first initial to variable using `f.substring(start position, length of string)`.
- 3.1.2    Concatenate first initial with users surname.
- 3.1.3    print username to console.

```
import java.util.Scanner; // imports scanner class

public class Assessment {
    public static void main(String[] args) { //main method

        menu();  //call menu method
    }

    public static void menu() { //method to display menu options
        int choice;
        String fName;
        String sName;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //displays menu options
        System.out.println("Welcome");
        System.out.println("1. Username");
        System.out.println("2. Factorial");
        System.out.println("3. Area of triangle");
        System.out.println("4. Circumference of circle");
        System.out.println("5. Exit");

        //asks for user input
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter your first name");
            fName = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter your surname");
            sName = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Thank you. Now enter a selection (1-5):");
            choice = sc.nextInt();
            //menu loop

            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    **stringOperation(String fName, String sName);**
                    break;
                case 2:
                    numberFactorial();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    areaTriangle();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    circumferenceCircle();
                    break;
            }

        }while (choice!=5);
    }
**//stringOperation method
    private static void stringOperation(String f, String s) {
        String initial = f.substring(0,1);
        String username = initial + s;
        System.out.println("Your username is " + initial + s);
    }**

    public static void numberFactorial() { //method to calculate factorial of a number

        //variables
        int number;
        int factorial = 1;
        int i;
        //input
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        number = sc.nextInt();
        //for loop
        for (i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
            factorial = factorial * i;
        }
        System.out.println("Factorial of " + number + " is " + factorial);
    }


    public static void areaTriangle ()//method to calculate area of a triangle
    {   //input
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //variables
        double width;
        double height;
        double area;
        //input
        System.out.println("Enter the width: ");
        width = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter height: ");
        height = sc.nextInt();
        area = (height * width) / 2;
        System.out.println("The area is :" + area);
    }

    public static void circumferenceCircle ()//method to calculate circumference of a circle
    {   //variables

        double radius;
        double circumference;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter radius: ");
        radius = sc.nextDouble();
        circumference = Math.PI * 2 * radius;
        System.out.println("The circumference is : " + circumference);

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have now?

Comment: Looks fine to me. You can replace `System.out.println("Your username is ".....)` with `System.out.printlnt("Your username is " + username)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, stringOperation(String fName, String sName); the error shows ')' expected after (String

Comment: How about `String username = String.format("%s%s",initial.charAt(0), s);`

Comment: Please include this information in your question. In any case, you should call the method as `stringOperation(fName, sName)`. You only include the type when defining it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the method cleaner you could do something like this

```
private static void stringOperation(String f, String s) {
    System.out.println("Your username is " + f.substring(0,1) + s)
}
```

If you need to refer back to the new username then have a global variable that your method can set to refer to later like this.

```
private static void stringOperation(String f, String s) {
    Assessment.username = f.substring(0,1) + s;
    System.out.println("Your username is " + Assessment.username);
}
```